# Function to change column name to the name of a variable

Tags: r

I want to use the below function and change the name of col1 to "hello_world" as specified in the function call.

```
change_name <- function(col1){
tidyr::expand_grid(col1 = iris$Species,
                   col2 = iris$Sepal.Length)}

change_name(col1="hello_world")
```

The above doesn't change the name of col1 to "hello_world", can anyone suggest any suggestions to the function to make this happen?

Comment: your function parameter `col1` is not used at all. The one inside `expand_grid` is defined for a new data frame.

Comment: I think this already exists in  `data.table::setnames()`.

Answer (score 0):

Argument names aren't interpreted. Use `names() <-` or `setNames` to assign column names. Like this:

```
change_name <- function(col1){
  result <- tidyr::expand_grid(
    col1 = iris$Species,
    col2 = iris$Sepal.Length
  )
  names(result)[1] <- col1
  result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function parameter *col1* is not used in your code block.

Here is a simple solution with *colnames()* function.

```
# generating data
data <- as.data.frame(tidyr::expand_grid(col1 = iris$Species,
            col2 = iris$Sepal.Length))

# function
change_name <- function(col1) {
  colnames(data)[1] <- col1
  data
}

# output
change_name(col1 = "hello_world")
```